# How to edit figure size in seaborn plot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, figure

I want to create 2 regplots from seaborn, both of which are subplots. I want to adjust the size of the figures but there is no attribute for figsize, height or aspect in sns.regplot. How do I alter the figsize?

**CODE**

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax0 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(122)

sns.regplot(x='Reputation',y='Views',data=df_users,ax=ax0)
sns.regplot(x='Reputation',y='UpVotes',data=df_users,ax=ax1)
```

Comment: `fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(10, 10))`?

Comment: This works, I have to remove ax0 and ax1 before writing this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pyplot.subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html); change

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax0 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(122)
```

to something like

```
fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(10, 10))
```

adjusting the `figsize` as desired.